# Javascript Subtract Dates

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a traffic light system that dynamically compares today to the due date, and populates a calculated column accordingly. I was able to code it, but the user changed requirements. Instead of the yellow traffic light showing if the item is due today, they want it to show if the item is due within the next 5 days.

I'd like to change it from "else if (fieldDate == today) " to five days before today. I can't figure out the proper way to create a today - 5 object in JavaScript. Help!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<!-- This script searches for calculated fields that are "marked" vith "Due:" and         -->
//<!-- Create a calculated field in the list with the following formula:                    -->
//<!-- =IF(DueDate="","N/A","Due: "&MONTH(DueDate)&"/"&DAY(DueDate)&"/"&YEAR(DueDate))      -->
//<!-- The data type returned from this formula is: Date and Time                           -->
// call script

findDatefields();
function findDatefields() {
    var d = new Date();
    var today = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()).getTime();
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // Check if it is "our field"

        if ((arr[i].className == "ms-vb2") && (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Due:") == 0)) {
            var sepDate = arr[i].innerHTML.substring(5).split("/", 3);
            var m = sepDate[0];
            var d = sepDate[1];
            var y = sepDate[2];

            // build the datestring
            var fieldDate = new Date(y, m - 1, d, 00, 00, 00).getTime();
            if (fieldDate > today) {
                arr[i].innerHTML = "<IMG src='_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.gif' Title='On track' />";
            }

            else if (fieldDate == today) {
                arr[i].innerHTML = "<IMG src='_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.gif' Title='Due today' />";

            }

            else {
                arr[i].innerHTML = "<IMG src='_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.gif' Title='Overdue' />";
            }
        }
    }
}

// For it to work in collapsed views

function ExpGroupRenderData(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbod" + groupName + "_");
    var wrapDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    wrapDiv.innerHTML = "<TABLE><TBODY id=\"tbod" + groupName + "_\" isLoaded=\"" + isLoaded + "\">" + htmlToRender + "</TBODY></TABLE>";
    tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapDiv.firstChild.firstChild, tbody);
    findDatefields();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistook your fieldDate and today to be Date objects when they're actually just longs (milliseconds). This is what you want to do.

```
else if ((fieldDate - today) <= 432000000)
```

The logic behind that is in one of my later comments.

If you want a single check against just the 5 days:

```
else if (fieldDate == (today + 432000000));
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. I would like to set a variable of 5 days before today and then compare it to that variable. The fieldDate has to be greater than or equal to Today - 5 (i.e. WITHIN the last 5 days)

Comment: Updated to do check WITHIN 5 days.

Comment: You can also replace the 5 with a variable that you set elsewhere.

Comment: When I implement this, it causes the Traffic Lights to stop working completely. Can you show me how to set a variable that is = today minus five?

Comment: `var lowTime = 5; //Declare this somewhere in the function and change it as you need to.
else if ((fieldDate.getDate()-today.getDate()) <= lowTime)`

Comment: or if you want to create a date object that is exactly at 5 days before today's date:

`var fiveBefore = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()-5);`

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed the fact that you were doing a .getTime() after and comparing those values. You'll need to multiply the 5 days by: 5 days * 24 hours/day * 60 min/hour * 60 sec/min * 1000 ms/sec to get your comparison value. So that 5 should actually be 432000000 (because getTime() returns a value in milliseconds).

Comment: So the issue that I'm having now is that it's EITHER making the stoplights red or yellow (so it catches either the first or second if statement). Should the clause be else if (fieldDate < today) && (fieldDate == (today + 432000000)); ---how would i turn that into an AND statement so that it only applies if the field date < today?

Comment: In theory, the order in which you check your conditions isn't important as long as you're catching all the cases. When you actually implement the code (for the sake of clarity as well as reducing the amount of testing) you should try to catch the exceptions and let the likely case fall though (into the else statement). The way I would do it is check for the worst case to the best case. I'd first check if the: if fieldDate == today (red), then id check if it was within 5 days: else if fieldDate - today < 5 (yellow). Every other case should display green (else).

Comment: It worked when I reworked the logic. Thanks a bunch!